# Why are deleted questions always considered as a bad thing?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I've just discovered that I'm banned from asking questions on SO and I'm really sad to see that. In total, I have 6 downvotes and 7 upvotes, so I don't understand why I'm considered as a "bad" user. I read in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) that one is downgrated for deleted questions too, but I don't fully agree with that. Namely, I have quite some deleted questions (I think that causes the banning), but I always deleted them *myself*, because I for example realised that they were more appropriate on Drupal Answers; because I misunderstood something about my situation making, my question irrelevant; etc. In my opinion, that only satisfies the wish for higher quality posts.

Am I wrong in saying this? Why are deleted questions always considered as a bad thing?

Comment: [[meta-tag:status-by-design]]

Comment: deleted questions are always taken into account because they are a negative contribution to the site. Someone who asks bad questions should not get out of his ban by sweeping all his rubbish under the carpet, right?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Who says deleted questions are always rubbish? The ones I deleted were not downvoted most of the time and I could have deleted the ones that were, but I didn't.

Comment: @JeffMercado: What does the `[status-bydesign]` tag mean? I don't really understand the explanation...

Comment: Pardon, I meant to link to [[meta-tag:status-bydesign]]. You're asking about whether or not having questions being deleted should be a bannable offense. This feature is like that by design and will not likely be changed unless there's a good strong case on why it should. While I agree we shouldn't just ban just because of how many questions there are, but the reason, it's not very practical to try to determine that in an automated fashion.

Comment: [status-bydesign tag wiki: This tag indicates that the bug/feature/observation it is attached to is intentional. That is to say, it is intentional *now that the Stack Exchange team knows about it*.

Whether or not it was *originally* intended is another story.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-bydesign/info)

Comment: And I accept that some (or all) of your questions you deleted are not rubbish. They are still no positive contribution as they are deleted, and what I meant is that that's the reason behind the design (maybe formulated too strong for you...).

Comment: @Deduplicator: No problem, I don't take it as an offence. I mentioned it to clarify my situation and my thoughts about the banning system. :)

Comment: Questions are meant to *help future users*. A deleted question cannot help anyone. A user that systematically deletes every question he asks (maybe after receiving an answer) is **not** a "good" user. In fact I have seen people doing this and explicitly stating that they didn't want to help future users. This is against the goal of SO and thus such users shouldn't be allowed to continue doing so. Banning them seems like the correct action.

Comment: @JeffMercado Deleting questions is annoying if people have spent time on comments and answers, but StackOverflow is very metrically able to tell how much "bandwidth" a question is taking; even to the point of knowing if there is someone trying to answer who hasn't finished their post yet.  One should be able to flag one's own post for review and hand it over to a yay or nay, or if there are just automated systems in action know where you stand with it *(if you delete this question, you will be unable to ask another for N days, read why `[link]`.  Are you sure?)*

Comment: If some of the questions would have been more appropriate on a different SE, then it probably would have been better to petition to have it migrated to the appropriate site.

Comment: @cimmanon: I agree, but in some cases, I asked the same question on a different SE website (namely Drupal Answers) before, but didn't get the respond I was hoping for. That's why I sometimes decided to post the question (in a slightly adapted version) on SO too.

Answer (score 16):

My understanding of the question ban (which is only pieced together from circumstantial evidence, like everyone else who isn't a SE employee) is that a deleted question is at best no different than an undeleted one, at worst only slightly worse.

The point is a bad question is a bad question whether deleted or not.  Someone who constantly asks bad questions shouldn't be able to escape punishment simply by deleting the question.  They need to be held accountable for the decisions they made to continue to ask bad questions and not learn from their poor choices.

---

But in general, the reason the the community considers deletions bad is because they consume resources.  Not necessarily the physical resources of Stack Overflow (but they do consume those resources too) but the human resources of everyone who touched the question

- You are wasting the time of every user who read the question, whether they decided to participate or not.
- Anyone who commented or edit tried to help you.  When you decide to delete, you basically eliminated their contributions.  Yes, the comments might have been the reason you decided to delete, but that's beside the point.  The fact that you deleted the questions means you felt that the question was unworthy of the site and it means that the time anyone spent on your question could have been spent helping another user.
- Anyone who answered (but did not get an upvote (yet)) or was in the process of answering basically wasted their time.  You took the effort they expended on trying to help you and threw it in the garbage.

The point is act of asking questions should be considered a consumable resource.  You aren't just posting a question on a magical site that automatically spits out answers, but on a site with actual humans on the other side who volunteer their time to help.  You are actually consuming the resources (in terms of time) of every single person who encounters your question and when you delete the question, you are basically saying to those people "the time you spent looking at my question and possibly trying to help me was worthless".

We want you to think hard **before** you ask the question, not after.  If you decide that it is a bad fit after you ask the question, you've already wasted people's time.  So we want you to think about it before asking so you don't waste anyone's time or efforts, and those efforts can be spent looking at other questions.

Comment: I realise this is a very old answer, but one of my [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481307/windows-authentication-in-net-core) just got some downvotes even after editing the question. Now, I was researching whether downvoted questions should be deleted and I came across this post. 

I understand everything you said, however, going by that logic, isn't it better to delete the question so as to not waste any more (human) resources, who might look at that question?

Comment: @JeevanJose no one said you couldn't or shouldn't delete it.  But the topic of this question specifically mentions the question ban why deleted questions still count.  One bad question never caused anyone to get banned.  The ban targets users who continually ask bad questions, never learn from them, and keep asking/deleting their bad content.  With 1700 rep, you have probably earned enough leeway to avoid a ban unless you asked a large number of bad/deleted question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment here and on my SO question. I ended up deleting it.

Comment: `We want you to think hard before you ask the question, not after.` -- Yes.  `Asking questions should be considered a consumable resource` -- Yes.  `in general, the reason the the community considers deletions bad is because they consume resources` -- No.  Deletion *conserves* resources.  It saves visitors from having to read bad questions to decide if they're worthwhile.  It saves Google searchers from having to sift through irrelevant results.  It saves new users who might otherwise ask more bad questions on the strength of a  bad, undeleted question.

Comment: For those folks who choose to answer bad questions, only to have the question deleted, c'est la vie.  They could have saved their time by not answering the bad question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting your own questions (that were not heavily down-voted, that's a separate issue) implies to me that you perhaps did not do your due diligence in researching your issue/topic before posting.
If your question later turned out to be off-topic then it should not really have been asked in the first place, right?

You are not Question banned for this happening once or twice but if it starts to become a habit then I see a cooling off period to take a look at what could be doing differently so as to improve the quality or validity of your Questions to be perfectly fair.