# Is it bad form to delete a question with downvotes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

Searching through SO, I regularly see new users posting questions that swiftly get a negative vote, upon which usually results in the offending question being removed. The question is then sometimes put back up in a slightly altered way, which can cause the whole process to repeat itself until an answer to the question is given.

My question is should a question have been altered to retain the downvotes and consequences of the initial query, or does the SO community think its okay to remove the question and hence avoid the removal of account 'score'?

As a disclaimer I should note that early on in the use of SO I did remove a question of my own because I was presented with pre-existing resolved questions. Should I have left the question as it stood, so that it could be voted to close?

Comment: You should **not** delete downvoted questions. That contributes to question ban. You should read this [excellent answer by psubsee2003](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265515/2982225) which explains why deleting posts is bad.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I agree it should be avoided, but what of the case of duplicates?

Comment: Duplicates serve a very useful purpose. People write the same question in different ways, and all point to the canonical answer. When you are searching with certain keywords, if your keywords are different, you may not find the canonical post, but if a duplicate exists which uses similar words like you, you find it quickly and reach the canonical answer. Think of it as signposts which point to the right direction. All the duplicates are actually different ways to ask the same thing. So every time you post a duplicate, you have helped SO create a new signpost.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Ah okay thank you, I think I'll still try to avoid duplicates like the plague though :)

Comment: New users deleting their own questions may result in an automatic ban.  Better to fix the issue than delete it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the question is un-salvageable then it should be deleted. However, this can have consequences for the the OP as deleted questions contribute to the automatic question ban - though down-voted ones do too so if it's down-voted anyway deleting isn't going to make much difference.

If the question is salvageable then it should be edited. This can be done by anyone, but preferably the OP. In some cases it might be worth the OP deleting the question to prevent further down-votes while they do more research etc. before editing the question into better shape and then un-deleting.

Comment: See that makes sense, I just find it a little strange that deleting a question removes any negative results from your 'points'. I understand that the gamification of the user profile system is to allow privileges, and should not be the be-all and end-all for a user, but for a new user it is much easier to delete a question to avoid losing 'score' and try again with another version of the question. Either way, thanks for answering my question

Comment: @PatrickDeveloper - If they do it too often they'll hit an automatic question block, so it's not a long term strategy.

Comment: Is this ban temporary? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The problem is when those who have both more knowledge and more reputation down vote beginner level questions that are genuine. Some SO users down vote without leaving a comment as to why, neither they edit the question or try to interact with the user. This is toxic in my opinion.

For those whose English isn't the first language (like myself) asking the questions has an extra difficulty (grammar, vocabulary, in addition to tech terminologies).

Users should indeed interact with OP positively, *specially if they are going to down vote the OP's question*.

As for the answer. Users should be striving for asking good questions: clear, well formatted, well articulated. And if my opinion, if you realize the question was just plain silly and for that reason it is getting down voted, then delete it. Silly questions are tricky to treat because editing won't make it better usually and the explanation for down votes becomes awkward since I assume most users won't want to say "well that was stupid to ask." (though usually they say things like "read the docs" or "this is easy to verify yourself" which are valid comments.)